# log4j2 cofiguration [Fatal Error] TKUat1_Log4j.cf:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, log4j2

Getting [Fatal Error] TKUat1_Log4j.cf:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
with below cofiguration for log4j2.properties file

```
rootLogger.level = DEBUG
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger

appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:LOGDIR}
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${LOGDIR}.%i.log
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=200MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern =%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} - %m\n
```

Comment: It appears that log4j2 is trying to read your "log4j2.properties" file as if it was an XML format configuration file.  There is insufficient detail in your question to understand why it is doing that.

Comment: -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$CF_LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE  I am using this vm arguement to set the configuration

Comment: If you are using log4j-2.10 or later, the property name should be "log4j2.configurationFile" - see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties

Comment: But what you really need to do is to add "-Dlog4j2.debug=true" to the options (temporarily) to see the internal debug messages that are emitted as log4j attempts to find and parse the configuration file.  That should provide the clues that you need to debug the problem.